# Why does Windows setup/installer continue to use an old temp directory?

Tags: windows-10, windows-installer, temporary-files

I recently moved my temporary folder from `D:\Temp` to `E:\Temp`, by changing my user account's `TEMP` and `TMP` environment variables. After rebooting, most programs are using `E:\Temp`, however every now and then a few files appear in `D:\Temp`.

After monitoring this folder using Resource Monitor, it appears that installation of applications or application components causes `D:\Temp` to be populated. The files generated do not seem to be specific to the installed application, but more like runtime environment stuff:
[image: temporary files]

**Why is Windows using this folder for temporary files, when it is no longer specified as the temporary folder location?** And how can I make Windows use the correct location?

What I have tried:

- Rebooting several times: no change.
- Verifying `$env:tmp` and `$env:temp` in Powershell for my user account and administrator: all are set correctly to `E:\Temp`.
- Checking the "system" `TMP` and `TEMP` variables: they remain as `C:\Windows\Temp` (have never been modified).

Answer (score 0):

Could it be updates to applications that were originally installed using `D:\Temp`?

- Are there still references to `D:\Temp` in registry keys like:

  ```
  HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
  ```

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer with the way it's worded

Comment: Plausible, but it definitely also happens for new applications I've never installed before.

Comment: Ah sorry, yes, hadn't realised I should put it as a comment. Will do next time; thanks.

Comment: Even if it happens for new applications, I still think it could be related to old installs, and I would guess it's coming from the registry. Have you already searched it for D:\Temp?

Comment: I have searched the registry for it, there are a few mentions of specific paths within D:\Temp (which are now deleted) for random applications which I don't have installed anymore or don't use.

Comment: In the meantime I believe I have narrowed it down to Visual Studio. Only 1 folder is ever created in D:\Temp and it always has the same name, and always contains Visual Studio type stuff. Now how on earth to figure out WHY it's making files there... I have searched through config files, app data files, registry, and so far I haven't found any mentions of it.